# Difficulty Setting Up Numpy for Python 2.7 on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, numpy

I'm trying to run a script of mine using Python 2.7.  When I run

```
python2.7
```

I get

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 25 2015, 13:06:17)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

When I try to run my script, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bcp.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

So Python 2.7 doesn't seem to know about numpy.  When I run

```
pip2.7 install numpy
```

I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
Cleaning up...
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you're using the wrong python distro on your computer. If you are using an OSX machine, there might be a python distribution in /usr/local/ and one in /System/Library/Frameworks. It seems like python2.7 might be linked to the one in /usr/.

Try

```html
which python2.7
```

should locate which python distro "python2.7" is symlinked to. If you're symlinked to /usr/, just change it to the one in /System/Library and your numpy should work.

Comment: then, just change your new pythonpath to the one linked in /Systems/Library